# Не работает сортировка pymysql

Tags: python, mysql, sql, pymysql

Код:

```
con = pymysql.connect(host = '123', user = '123', password = '123', database = '123')

cur = con.cursor()

cur.execute("""CREATE TABLE users(id INT(15),
    money INT(255)
    )""")



def send_message(user_id, message, keyboard=None):
    post = {
        "user_id": user_id,
        "message": message,
        "random_id": 0
    }
 
    if keyboard != None:
        post["keyboard"] = keyboard.get_keyboard()
 
    session.method("messages.send", post)
 
for event in VkLongPoll(session).listen():
    if event.type == VkEventType.MESSAGE_NEW and event.to_me:
        text = event.text.lower()
        user_id = event.user_id
        if text == 'топ игроков':
            cur.execute('SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY money DESC')
            con.commit()
```

При отправке команды боту список не сортируется.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно это исправить?

Comment: А где код, который читает результат запроса? Может там проблема.

Comment: вы про con = pymysql.connect(host = '123', user = '123', password = '123', database = '123')?

Comment: Нет, ну вот вы сделали запрос к `SQL` через `cur.execute('SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY money DESC')`, а результат запроса как-то же вы обрабатываете дальше? Может вы его там опять сортируете, или пишете в словарь и сортировка теряется, или... я много вариантов могу придумать.

Comment: Всё, я исправил баг. Проблема была в моей невнимательности. Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: Что было то хоть? ))

Comment: Там кнопка вызывала другую команду, поэтому не изменялось значение в базе данных).

Comment: Вряд ли это был повод чтобы плодить [дубликаты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1297874/%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%80%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bb-sql)